# OL3+ Angular bring the marker(Icon) on top when clicked

Tags: angularjs, icons, z-index, openlayers-3, markers

I am very new to OL3 and I have a scenario where we are using OL3 3.4.0+AngularJs, I have to bring the marker(Icon) on top when clicked, even if its behind some other icon. Please let me know if its achievable.

Thank you :)

Comment: It is achievable but you will have to show some context.

Comment: I have a situation where I am clicking on the marker and the label for  the marker I am rendering at the same time, If this marker is overlapped by some other marker on the same or nearby location I need to bring this marker to front and may be higlighted

....For getting the markers I am using ol-marker directive and passing the ol-marker-properties to render the marker and setting the label mesage to show on click event.

Comment: Since you are new to OL3, I strongly recommend you to learn it first without any proxy, take the official examples and work on them.

Comment: Sure @Jonatas I am doing that :)